# How to Turn off Samsung CH711 Monitor without removing cable

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

I have 2 Samsung CH711 27" curved monitors connected via HDMI, and I would like to make then fully turn off (ie no flashing blue light when the PC is put to sleep or shutdown).

Is there something I am missing in the configuration that makes blue light at the bottom of the monitor flash.

I have gone into the menu and set the Power Led On - Working and I've also trying Stand-By, neither makes a difference.

I would prefer that I can flick a switch or toggle a setting rather than needing to turn the power off at the wall (awkward).

Answer (score 0):

I have that monitor since 2 years now and there's no way to turn off that light, the only solution is to cover it with something or maybe you could try to open the monitor to see if there's a cable that can be cutted (not recommended).